# Motorcycle questions referred over from bicycles.se

Tags: discussion, scope

With respect to this question
https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/38695/why-do-some-2-wheelers-have-an-attachment-to-their-fork

- Its definitely off topic for the Bicycles.SE site.
- motorcycles.SE didn't get going  http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6788/motorcycles

So is it an acceptable on-topic question for this stack?   Or is there another place it would be better suited, like an industrial design stack?

I honestly don't know - what's the collective opinion?

Comment: _If_ it was a motorcycle question, it was on topic here.  The problem is the picture and very short description didn't really show exactly what the "two-wheeler" was.  In other words, it was a good migration, but the question was poor for _any_ SE.

Comment: @JPhi1618 agreed it was a poorly written question, but it did have a photo which is worth a thousand words right there.   Getting the question to the right place is higher priority than rewriting the text however.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, motorcycle is a motor vehicle, so the "Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair" community is the place to go. We have plenty of motorcycle questions here.

Answer (score 12):

Motorcycle questions are on-topic here - in fact we have some very knowledgeable Motorbike people here (@DucatiKiller in particular)